# Raspberry Pi3 Lidar mapping hector mapping error

Tags: raspberry-pi, mapping, ros, lidar, slam

Hi I'm new on the ros and actually I don't know anything but I have a project and I  installed ubuntu on raspberry pi 3 and I installed ros and I followed instructions on this repo https://github.com/NickL77/RPLidar_Hector_SLAM but when I launch tutorial.launch it gives this error.

```
ERROR: cannot launch node of type [hector_mapping/hector_mapping]: Cannot locate node of type [hector_mapping] in package [hector_mapping]. Make sure file exists in package path and permission is set to executable (chmod +x)
process[base_to_laser_broadcaster-3]: started with pid [25073]
ERROR: cannot launch node of type [hector_trajectory_server/hector_trajectory_server]: Cannot locate node of type [hector_trajectory_server] in package [hector_trajectory_server]. Make sure file exists in package path and permission is set to executable (chmod +x)
ERROR: cannot launch node of type [hector_geotiff/geotiff_node]: Cannot locate node of type [geotiff_node] in package [hector_geotiff]. Make sure file exists in package path and permission is set to executable (chmod +x)
```

Comment: Did you install it via source or apt? You need to make sure you're sourcing the correct `setup.bash`

Comment: I installed it via source and yes I'm %100 sure that I'm sourcing correct setup.bash when I tried to launch rplidar view it shows me lidar datas in rziv but when I launched hector slam It gave me this error

Comment: If you're sourcing the `devel/setup.bash` in your workspace, and not `/opt/`, I'd think the package isn't building correctly. Do you actually see binaries that are built? It could also be an issue with what ROS distro you're using, but I think that's less likely.

Comment: When I run rospack find hector_mapping it gives me correctly position of this package when I Googling question I saw that some people solve this with catkin_make but when I ran that terminal gave error and said that there are uncatkin packages so run catkin_make_isolated but when I ran that my raspberry pi 3 frozing and I can't access it(I ran catkin make after I installed rplidar package and it was successful )

Comment: And yes I'm sourcing devel/setup.bash,my lidar sensor and lidar rziv working fine but when I tried to add hector slam  it gives this error and I don't know what to do

Comment: How are you actually building the package then if `catkin_make` fails? Are you using `catkin build`?

Comment: I clone git repo rplidar package in my src folder and I ran catkin_make and it's working fine after that I clone  hector slam git repo in my src folder should I use catkin make again I'm sorry Im new in the Ros if I need to do that when I ran catkin make it gives errors which I mentioned

Comment: No worries. Yes, you would need to rebuild. I've posted an answer that should give more details.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your comments there are really two options here. The issue you're running into is because `hector_slam` isn't actually being built. After you clone a new repo you must build the new packages before you attempt to use them. This is because ROS repos typically only contain the source code and `CMake` handles creating binaries for your specific distro.

Since it is only `hector_slam` that is causing you issues, you can actually install this via apt. This would look like: `sudo apt install ros-noetic-hector-slam`. Note that this command will change depending on your ROS distro. [The wiki page](http://wiki.ros.org/hector_slam) is also a good source for documentation.

Your second option is to use `catkin_make_isolated`, but based on your comments this is most likely failing due to resource constraints. If you have another machine with the same architecture, you could build the files there and then copy over the binaries; I wouldn't exactly recommend this, though.

Comment: Thank you but when I tried to install via apt I got E: unable to locate hector-slam package error :( so is my raspberry pi 3 is not enough capacity for this job ?

Comment: @BurakEren are you using the full name? i.e. including the `ros-noetic-` part? That error means the apt repos don't see that package. You can also search by using `apt list | grep hector`

Comment: Yes I'm using full name